# why does this line remove everything instead of one line. Crontab-Bash-Sed

Tags: linux, bash, cron, cron-task

I need to remove a line of a cron file but when I use this bash script code it removes everything from the cron file and doesn't overwrite it with the new result.

I choose which line to remove with a variable that is read as a number shown below:

```
read $lineToRemove

crontab -l | sed "${lineToRemove}d" | crontab -
```

From my understanding of this, i read the user input if they write the number 2 and press enter. Then the crontab file is listed in the first part of the pipe line. Then the `sed` function is used to remove the line at the specified number in the variable and the result is written back to the cron file. Yet when i do this it removes everything from the cron file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read`'s parameter should exclude `$`, just like `var=value` excludes `$`. You're `read`ing into a variable named `$lineToRemove`, not `lineToRemove`.

```
$ read x 
hi
$ echo $x
hi
$ read $x 
hi
$ echo $hi
hi
```

When I `read $x`, the variable that stores the value is `$x`, not `x`, eg `hi`.  so `$hi` subsequently refers to the thing read into `$x`.